# python pdb automatic pretty-printing

Tags: python, pdb

I find myself doing this in pdb quite often:

```
import pprint
pprint.PrettyPrinter().pprint(variable_of_interest)
```

Is there a better way to pretty-print variables from pdb? I'm looking for something easier to type, and ideally something that's always available in pdb so I can use it anytime I'm debugging.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In `pdb` documentation at the section [*Debugger Commands*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands):

> *pp expression*
>
> Like the *p* command, except the value of the expression is pretty-printed using the `pprint` module.

Comment: @nonagon welp i've been using python for years and also didn't know about `pdb`'s `pp`.

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith Haha yes, after years I just thought it would be great if pprint is loaded by default, how can I do it, then stumbled upon this.

Answer (score 6):

Like @enrico.bacis has mentioned `pp` can be used for pretty printing while using pdb.

```
(Pdb) pp your_var
```

Answer (score 3):

Once you are in (Pdb) shell:

```
(Pdb)$ import pprint

# then you can pretty print your variables.
(Pdb)$ pp( locals() )
(Pdb)$ pp(request.data)
```

---

Also, I recommend using the new pdb alternative `breakpoint()`, that way you don't have to import pdb package in any of your dev environment sourcecode. It's also easier to type than `pdb.set_trace()`

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I am doing it:

```
import pdb
import pprint

"""
Debugging views
pdb.set_trace()

With pretty-print
pp(my_var)
"""
def my_view(request):
    pdb.set_trace()
    # rest of view
```

Then in debugger:

```
> (Pdb) pp(my_var)
```

Although, I would like to know how to edit the pdb settings to change `p` to `pp`